# R Calculate Deviance Residuals in a Logistic Regression

Tags: r, regression, logistic, residuals, deviance

I am working on a project, where I want to build a function which performs a logistic regression but does not use the glm() function.

I ran in a little bit of difficulties, when it comes to calculate the deviance residuals. I looked up the underlying formula, but it is quite hard to for me to apply it in R.  I would appreciate every help in the regard.
As my code is pretty messed up right now, we will assume that my own logistic regression function produces the same outputs as the glm() function but not the deviance residuals:

This is an example where I calculated the Pearson Residuals by hand:

```
x <- c(1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10)
y <- c(1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0,1,0)
data <- data.frame(cbind(x,y))

model1 <- glm(y ~ x, data=data,  family = "binomial")

#Pearson Residuals:

fit <- model1$fitted.values
PResiduals <- (y - fit) / (diag((fit) %*% t(1 - fit)))^0.5
print(PResiduals)
```

> 0.75747 -1.24114  0.85700 -1.09700  0.96960 -0.96960  1.09700 -0.85700  1.2411498 -0.7574760

Check for correctness:

```
print(resid(model1, type = "pearson"))
```

> 0.75747 -1.24114  0.85700 -1.09700  0.96960 -0.96960  1.09700 -0.85700  1.2411498 -0.7574760

If someone could help me using the arguments of the model1 to calculate the deviance residuals I would be extremely thankful!

Comment: This link will come in handy: [Residuals in glm](https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/BinomTools/inst/ResidualsGLM.pdf?revision=6&root=binomtools&pathrev=6)

Comment: What is the difficulty, problem or question? Where do you get stuck?

Comment: I get stuck implementing the formula of the deviance residuals in R. (https://r-forge.r-project.org/scm/viewvc.php/*checkout*/pkg/BinomTools/inst/ResidualsGLM.pdf?revision=6&root=binomtools&pathrev=6). Im unsure which arguments correspond to the yi_hat and how to apply the "sgn" bracket. It would be great to know which arguments of model1 example correspond to which variable of the formula.

Comment: Thanks for the Link, but I particularly struggle in implementing Formula (3) in R.

Comment: The Formula can be taken from here, sorry for the wrong Link.  ( https://stats.stackexchange.com/a/396208/240297)

Comment: I guess the real question is why implement an alternative to glm when the current one works fine as it is?  Did you try edit(residuals.glm) or edit(glm.summaries) to see how those functions compute deviance residuals?

Comment: I'd like to understand why you can't use `glm` for this?  If you can help us understand your concerns with `glm`, I think we could provide better direction.  So what is the issue with `glm`?

Comment: I am well aware that glm() provides results in this regard but I hope to get a better insight into logistic regression by creating such statistics without the help of the glm() function. The Deviance Residuals are now the last statistic which I am not able to compute "by hand". It just annoys me a little to be so close and now struggle with the last step.